# spirit SA attribute numbers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Using phoenix, with a rule like this:

```
start_ = ( Rule1[SA1] >> +Rule2[SA2] >> Rule3 )
[ SA ];
```

Is it correct that, inside SA,

- _1 is Rule1's attribute
- _2 is (+Rule2)'s attribute
- _3 is Rule3's attribute?

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Also, `qi::_0` is the combined attribute (i.e. a Fusion tuple of `(qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3)`)

Comment: what about if Rule1's attribute is identical to Rule2's attribute (Rule2, not +Rule2) ? still the same ?

Comment: Yes (why would it make a difference?)